# How to set App Icons in Xcode 6.0.1

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, icons, xcode6

I am Setting up one of my old app with `xcode 6.0.1` but It not showing up the icons on device as well as simulator.

Deleting the `Images.xcassets` not worked for me

[image]

as I was expecting that it will show me the listing of the icon where, I can select add Icons.
Then i tried to set the Icons via `Images.xcassets` but no luck it don't show up on device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

click on the Images.xcassets and on the right side view check for + icon and you can add the app icon from there.[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use image.xcassests there is an option for app icon images to be added for iPhone and iPad both if the app is universal. 
and another option to add is on the right side view check for + icon and you can add the app icon.

Answer (score 0):

Is it critical whether to use xcassets catalog or not? If not, you may check your icon file in bundle resources and set it in app's plist file(delete other icons if they existed).